# Traversing to the nth level

Tags: collections, neo4j, cypher, traversal

I'm at a loss.

Scenario:  get depth of 2 from Joe (#'s represent 'Person'. Letters represent 'Position')

```
    0              E
    |              |
    1              B 
 /  |  \         / | \
2  JOE  3       C  A  D
   /|\            /|\
  0 0 0          F G H
 /\ | |         /\ | | 
0 0 0 0        I J K L
```

Catch is, a person is tied to a position. Position has relationships to each other but a person doesn't have a relationship to another person. so it goes something like:

```
Joe<-[:occupied_by]-(PositionA)-[:authority_held_by]->
(PositionB)-[:occupied_by]->Sam
```

This query:

```
Match (:Identity {value:"1234"})-[:IDENTIFIES]->(posStart:Position)
-[:IS_OCCUPIED_BY]->(perStart:Person) 
Optional Match p=(perStart)<-[:IS_OCCUPIED_BY]-(posStart)
-[r:AUTHORITY_HELD_BY*..1]-(posEnd:Position)-[:IS_OCCUPIED_BY]->
(perEnd:Person) Return p
```

does get me what I need but always returns the first column as the original node it started with (perStart). I want to return it in a way where the first two column always represent the start node and the second column to represent the end node.

```
PositionA, PositionB  (and we can infer this means A-[:authority_held_by]->B
```

If we had bi directional relationship, such as, A-[:authority_held_by]->B and B-[:manages]->A
I wouldn't mind what's in the first or the second column as we can have the third column represent the relationship

```
PositionB, PositionA, [:manages]
```

but we are trying to stay away from bi-directional relationship

Ultimately I want something like:

```
PositionA, PositionB   (inferring, A-[:A_H_B]->B)
PositionB, PositionE   (inferring, B-[:A_H_B]->E)
PositionF, PositionA   (inferring, F-[:A_H_B]->A)
PositionG, PositionA   (inferring, G-[:A_H_B]->A)
```

Is this possible with cypher or do I have to do some black magic? :)

I hope I explained throughly and understandably.. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Hi there. It's a little difficult to see what you are after. Is it possible for you to write up a more detailed example and maybe make a query up, just to get across what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @KoalaD - please edit your question with clarifications; don't post additional information in comments.

Answer (score 0):

ok - so the base query you are looking for is:
match (m)-[*0..2]-(n) where m.name = 'Joe' return m,n

however, I can't seem to get a parameter to substitute for the '2' - plus, when I try to do a reference for the link, e.g. r:*0..2 - it really doesn't like that.  After playing around with it - here's the closest I've gotten:

match p=(m)-[has_a_position_of|is_occupied_by|manages|managed_by*0..4]-(n:Person) where m.name='Joe' and length(p) <= {depth} return distinct n

where {depth} is your parameter for max depth of the request, the 0..4 is your 'max allowable depth' and has_a_position_of|is_occupied_by|manages|managed_by are relationship types in your db.  I can't find a way to make it generic for any relationship right now, and performancewise it's pretty sloppy - I'll peck away at it - but likely someone else can help refine this.

Comment: Dan, thanks for you input. I tried using your example but for some reason it gets the depth of other relationships as well. So, whatever relationship it finds it goes to the nth depth. Also, if you look at my comment to the @Andres it gets a bit complicated because a person is not connected to another person but through a position. So using your query I technically have to have 3 depth. PersonA -> positionA -> positionB -> PersonB. I tried getting my peers by inputing '4' as the depth but that gave me way more than two relationships I gave in the query.

Comment: if you're just looking for people, replace (n) with criteria that will just return people - if you're using labels, something like (n:Person) - if you're using other properties, add in "and n.type='Person'" - I've updated my answer...

Comment: Let's not post discussions as answers (as the answer posted is not an answer, and you're now discussing the possibilities in comments, another not-good thing).

Comment: Thanks Dan! I'm still having issue and I need to really consider if this is the best way or going about things. If you can suggest a different way, or a better way, I'm all ears. Thanks a lot!
@DavidMakogon I edited the question. Thanks for the suggestion. But How do you discuss without comments?

Comment: @KoalaD - I think you misunderstood me. You're adding details of your question into comments, which become very difficult to connect to the original question. And you're adding comments to an answer that risks being deleted, because it's not an actual answer (it's a few assertions and a hope that someone else can help out). If that non-answer is deleted, then so are all of your comments with extra details. So... edit your question. Then additional clarification questions can be added in comments to the question (and you can keep editing the question in response to these).